# Selecting TOP 1 of one column, grouping by a repeating ID with other unique fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with a query of data I need just one row of for EACH account in a table (thousands), based on selecting the highest sequence in a different column (Account_Occupant).

I need to return a distinct account number (90006), the highest account_occupant (11) and name corresponding to that account_occupant (MICHAEL).  Here is a sample of data:

```
Account_NUM Account_Occupant    Name
90006           1               JOHN
90006           2               MARY
90006           3               MARY
90006           4               KERRI
90006           5               PATRICIA
90006           6               DARYL
90006           7               ASHLEY
90006           8               DARYL
90006           9               DIANE
90006           10              DARYL
90006           11              MICHAEL
```

An example of what I need returned is:

```
Account_NUM Account_Occupant    Name
90006           11              MICHAEL
```

Here is a recent query attempt:

```
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT CIS.Account_NUM
        ,(
            SELECT top 1 CISa.Account_Occupant 
            FROM database.view CISa 
            WHERE CISa.Account_NUM = CIS.Account_NUM 
            ORDER BY CISa.Account_Occupant DESC
         ) AS Newest_Occupt_Num
    , CIS.name
    FROM database.view CIS
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 CIS2.Account_Occupant 
            FROM database.view CIS2 
            WHERE CIS.Account_NUM = CIS2.Account_NUM 
            AND CIS.Account_Occupant = CIS2.Account_Occupant 
            ORDER BY CIS2.Account_NUM, CIS2.Account_Occupant DESC
        )
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

I have done a fair amount of searching and trying variations of group by, group by in the where statement, sub-selects and union statements that I have found in this forum, but still not getting it right.  Apologies for the edits ask folks as questions pointing out the mistakes in my questioning - much appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear with only one `Account` value in your sample data.   Why do you say you need grouping?  As written, all you need is a simple ORDER BY.

Comment: Thank you, Tab - I have attempted to ask a more clear question in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach you can try.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL(Account_NUM VARCHAR(100),Account_Occupant INT,Name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TBL
SELECT '123',11,'ABC'

INSERT INTO TBL
SELECT '123',12,'XYZ'


INSERT INTO TBL
SELECT '124',11,'ABC'


INSERT INTO TBL
SELECT '124',12,'XYZ'


SELECT DISTINCT T.*, T1.Name FROM
(
   SELECT Account_NUM, MAX(Account_Occupant) OVER (PARTITION BY Account_NUM) AS MAX_Account_Occupant
   FROM TBL
 ) T
 INNER JOIN TBL T1 ON T1.Account_NUM= T.Account_NUM AND T1.Account_Occupant=T.MAX_Account_Occupant
```

Output

```
    Account_NUM MAX_Account_Occupant    Name
   ------------ --------------------   ----- 
    123               12                XYZ
    124               12                XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your description correctly, you don't need grouping. A simple descending order will give you want you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Account_NUM, Account_Occupant, Name
FROM table1
ORDER BY Account_Occupant DESC
```

If there are other records in your database with `Account_NUM` other than then  `90006` in your question, and you only want this `Account_NUM`, then simply add a condition:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Account_NUM, Account_Occupant, Name
FROM table1
WHERE Account_NUM = 90006
ORDER BY Account_Occupant DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option if you are looking for the top 1 **PER Account_Num**.

I submit this only because you were looking a GROUP BY and JOINs

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable 
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Account_NUM Order By Account_Occupant Desc)
```